# Edit or replace app.config file in Jenkins build

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild

I want to run automated tests using Specflow via Jenkins.
I have created a build that connects to TFVC and I am able to use the MSBuild step to build the Visual Studio project.
I have made the tests configurable so have a App.config file and Default.srprofile file.
I want to be able to edit/replace these files using the Jenkins build.
so far I have tried both the "Config File Provider Plugin" & "Text File Operations" plugins with build steps.
Every time the build tries to edit/replace these files I get the following error:

```
Creating/updating file at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\NAMEOFBUILD/AutomationFolder/App.config'
File already exists at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\NAMEOFBUILD/AutomationFolder/App.config', selected write option is 'overWrite'
Failed to create/update file. C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\NAMEOFBUILD\AutomationFolder\App.config
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\NAMEOFBUILD\AutomationFolder\App.config
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.FilePath$37.invoke(FilePath.java:1922)
    at hudson.FilePath$37.invoke(FilePath.java:1918)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:998)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:976)
    at hudson.FilePath.write(FilePath.java:1918)
    at com.etas.jenkins.plugins.CreateTextFile.CreateFileTask.call(CreateFileTask.java:105)
    at com.etas.jenkins.plugins.CreateTextFile.CreateFileTask.call(CreateFileTask.java:39)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at com.etas.jenkins.plugins.CreateTextFile.CreateFileBuilder.perform(CreateFileBuilder.java:95)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:735)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:490)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Build step 'Create/Update Text File' marked build as failure
```

If I edit/replace a file that does not exist in my project it seems to work. What is stopping it from updating the App.config file?

Comment: Here is a successful output where I have simply changed the filename from App.config to Appconfig:
Creating/updating file at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\NAMEOFBUILD/AutomationFolder/Appconfig'
File already exists at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\NAMEOFBUILD/AutomationFolder/Appconfig', selected write option is 'overWrite'
File successfully created/updated at C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\NAMEOFBUILD/AutomationFolder/Appconfig
Finished: SUCCESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a **D'oh!** moment.
Jenkins sets all the files under the workspace folder to read-only.

I just added a "Windows batch command" step before with:

```
attrib -r AutomationFolder\App.config
```

to make the file read-write and the next step then passes successfully.